# Django app with potentially very long task run-time

Tags: django, asynchronous

I have a Django app which lets the user execute (potentially very) time consuming computations. This is not an issue per se as the user is aware of the long runtime.

**How can I have the user execute tasks and then log out (or terminate the web app) while keeping the task running on the server**? i.e. The Django app should execute regardless of whether the website is still open or the user is still logged on.

Full disclosure, I am a beginner in web dev so my question may require refinement.

Comment: You use some queueing technology like rabbitMQ: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/20/how-to-use-celery-with-django.html

Answer (score 0):

I would go oldschool, let the user request save some data about the task and a cron job every minute would check new user tasks and run them :)

Comment: This is what I am thining to do, I just don't have the knowledge / jargon to start googling the solution.

Comment: I'm new to django, so I can't help with that much, but I suppose it runs on a linux server, so about cron check this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto .
I dont know yet, how to run properly django tasks in cron, but just google it.
And in your View when you get the request, you either put some info into db, or write a json file with the data you need for running the task...
But If you run the cron job every minute, be sure to prevent running the same user-task more than once by putting some attribute into json/db - like "status": "new"/"running"/"finished"/"error"

Answer (score 0):

You use an async task queue:

https://github.com/Bogdanp/dramatiq

https://github.com/celery/celery

https://github.com/closeio/tasktiger

Comment: Thank you I will look into this as well.